# tr command failing in bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I wrote a bash script that I use regularly. All of a sudden next command fails with error `[:lower:]: command not found. I used the script for quite a while, so this command worked before.

```
PROJECTTITLE="$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${PROJECTNAME:0:1})${PROJECTNAME:1}"
```

The command converts a string variable to Title case and saves it in another variable.

When executing the same code in the console, it works properly.

I'm on macOS Mojace 1.14.2, bash version 3.2.57(1)-release.

Comment: Can you show the exact line you wrote, because the above line will fail for obvious reasons.

Comment: "[:lower:]: command not found" means that `[:lower:]` is the first token of the line or subshell and that `bash` therefore tries to parse it as a command. This may be due to an incorrect alias, for instance I can reproduce with `alias tr='"$@"'`. I suggest using `set -x` to see what your command is expanded into

Comment: Unless you want to run this script on specifically macOS boxes out of your control, I strongly suggest installing a recent version of `bash` and simply using `PROJECTITLE=${PROJECTNAME^}`.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE).

Comment: @Aaron thanks, I did exactly that :/

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to involve an external command and a subshell; Bash has case modification built in! *edit: since version 4.0*

```
PROJECTNAME=${PROJECTNAME,,} # convert all characters to lowercase
PROJECTTITLE=${PROJECTNAME^} # convert first character to uppercase
```

Comment: Think I tried this one earlier. It returns an error ${PROJECTNAME^}: bad substitution. Wasn't this bash 4+ functionality? Perhaps I should upgrade....

Comment: You're right, these Parameter Expansions were added in 4.0 (2009).

Comment: What's the output of `type tr`? You could try `\tr` or `command tr`.